# What do you call people who are not patients?

Tags: synonyms

What do you call people who are not patients when you compare some data between patients who have a certain disease and people who don't have a certain disease.I want to describe the difference of dietary habit between diabetes patients and people who don't have diabetes. How do I name the people who don't have diabetes?
I did some researches, the following options are the result of research
**Healthy people, normal people,and fitted people** However, these several terms do not actually make any sense, and they are not accurate.

Comment: I'd suggest "people *without* diabetes".

Comment: Non-diabetic is an accepted term (and it is unambiguous).

Comment: A common term would be a 'control group' of patients. This means that these are patients that are healthy and often used in science to compare the effects of something.

Comment: @MickSharpe this term however may include people with other medical issues. For example if i were to use a group of 'non-diabetic' patients, this could include people with asthma, or other medical ailments.

Comment: "Yeh et al. (abstract 265) determined the risks of incident cancer, cancer death, and all-cause death after cancer in adults with versus without diabetes in a cohort of 20,703 individuals without known cancer, 570 of whom had diabetes." https://www.niddk.nih.gov/health-information/clinical-trials/Pages/default.aspx

Comment: Why not "disease-free"? Also "patients" as used in your title is not accurate because "patients" refers to a treatment status (like a patient in the hospital or doctors office), not whether or not you have a disease.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the people you're compiling data on are called *subjects*. You can compare data from *healthy subjects* with that from *diabetes patients*.

> **Subject** *noun*
>   1.2 A person who is the focus of scientific or medical attention or experiment.
>   *‘subjects were asked to complete a questionnaire’*
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/subject)